# print statements in super constructor don't print

Tags: python, constructor, init, super

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print("A")

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        super()
        print("B")

B()
```

This code prints `"B"`. My expectation was that it would print

```
A
B
```

or at least

```
B
A
```

. 
Why does it only print B?

Comment: Well, you are not using `A()` at all, neight in main nor in `B()`. Also: What is `super()`?

Answer (score 3):

1. class B does not inherit of class A
2. This is not the good syntax, super does not call constructor, it returns reference to parent class (and must be passed the type of current class and a reference to it (self))

Correction:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    print "A"

class B(A): # Inherit A class
  def __init__(self):
    super(B, self).__init__()  # Call A constructor
    print "B"
```

Answer (score 1):

`super` by itself just returns a reference to the parent class. You actually need to call the relevant method:

```
 super().__init__()
```